# Android App development - File access | input

Tags: android, mobile

Hi I am developing a Private key singing app.

I need to be able choose different types of file to be signed. However until now I have just found a way to input file from photo galary and videos..

At least I need to be able to access the pdf/txt file at the device through my app.

Anyone knows how to do it ?
Because using File and FileInputStream in java I know, I just don't know which component I can use as input  in the layout.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can add intent filters for various file types to be an option for handling those on behalf of other selector apps.  Or you can look at incorporating something like the open intents file browser in order for a user already in your app to go and select a file.

Comment: Hi Chris thak you for your answer. I am new at Android development....i don't understand intents very well yet. Do you have a place where I can see a example of this?? thanks you

Comment: I'd suggest you do a search on OpenIntents, and also on something like "intent filter for file type".  Basically Android as conceived by Google doesn't have the desktop-style concept of file browsing (or to a degree, even user-exposed raw files) but only ways for apps to hand content off to each other.  But it's entirely possible to add this with 3rd party code, so you can either let your users browse for files using something like the OI File Browser, or you can register to handle content they find Android-style with other apps, or you can do both.

Comment: Thank you very muh @ChrisStratton. I have found this 3rd party https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/ .... i will try to use this. thank you for your time